# Biblatex/Biber is removing the word "company" from publisher field

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-mla

I am using biblatex for bibliography management, with Biber as a backend and `style=mla-new`. I have the following bibliographic entry in my *.bib:

```
@inbook{theodyssey,
  title = "The Odyssey",
  author = "Homer",
  translator = "Stanley Lombardo",
  booktitle = "The Norton Anthology of Western Literature",
  edition = "9",
  pages = "291-581",
  publisher = {W. W. Norton \& Company},                                                                                                        
  year = "2014"
}
```

Almost everything prints correctly. However, the bibliographic entry looks like this:

```
Homer, "The Odyssey", The Norton Anthology of Western Literature, translated by
  Stanley Lombard, 9th ed., W. W. Norton &, 2014, pp. 291-581
```

Notice how the word "company" is stripped off of W. W. Norton & Company. I can't figure out how to fix this, or even why it's happening.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Indeed, `mla-new` includes `\step[fieldsource=publisher, match=\regexp{Company|Co\.|Corporation|Corp\.|Incorporated|Inc\.|Limited|Ltd\.}, replace={}]` in a sourcemap. That is, it strips all of those terms from `publisher` and means this is a style requirement/decision. Furthermore, I'm not sure it is easy to override it. `mla` doesn't do the same, if that's an alternative for you.

Comment: Thank you, switching to `mla` from `mla-new` resolved the issue. I had it set to `mla-new` because I sometimes use web sources and prefer the new style in that case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The style `mla-new` includes the following step in its `StyleSourcemap`:

```
\step[fieldsource=publisher, match=\regexp{Company|Co\.|Corporation|Corp\.|Incorporated|Inc\.|Limited|Ltd\.}, replace={}]
```

which strips all of those terms from the `publisher` field. As this is done with a sourcemap, it is hard to override it, as it affects the data itself.

This must mean, though, that this is part of the requirements of the MLA style in it's 8th edition, which is implemented by `mla-new`.

The style `mla` does not include such a sourcemap step, and could be used if that is an alternative for you, and you don't want to comply with this characteristic of the newest version of the style.

However, the `biblatex-mla` documentation mentions the following:

> This beta update is for testing compatibility with the 8th edition of the MLA Handbook, published April 2016. This current version supports both the old edition (by using `style=mla` in the preamble) and the newer edition (using `style=mla-new`); an upcoming version of biblatex-mla will deprecate support for the 7th edition in favor of the 8th.

An alternative with `mla-new` would be to cheat the sourcemap substituting the word with a macro, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla-new]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcommand*{\Co}{Company}

% filecontents is used here for convenience, in your actual document, the entry would be in your regular .bib file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{theodyssey,
  title = "The Odyssey",
  author = "Homer",
  translator = "Stanley Lombardo",
  booktitle = "The Norton Anthology of Western Literature",
  edition = "9",
  pages = "291-581",
  publisher = {W. W. Norton \& \Co},
  year = "2014"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: I found a way to override the sourcemap step, using the sequence in which the different types of sourcemaps are applied. (user) `\DeclareSourcemap`s are run first, so we can use this to copy the original data from `publisher` to the field `listf`. `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` comes second. Luckily they can be used multiple times, and are applied in order of definition. As the original one is defined with the style (that is, with the call to `biblatex`), we can define a second one later, copying back the data from `listf` to `publisher`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla-new]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=publisher, fieldset=listf, origfieldval]
        }
    }
}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=listf, fieldset=publisher, origfieldval]
        }
    }
}

% filecontents is used here for convenience, in your actual document, the entry would be in your regular .bib file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{theodyssey,
  title = "The Odyssey",
  author = "Homer",
  translator = "Stanley Lombardo",
  booktitle = "The Norton Anthology of Western Literature",
  edition = "9",
  pages = "291-581",
  publisher = {W. W. Norton \& Company},
  year = "2014"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```